# xlsxwriter: duplicate worksheet within same workbook

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am working on a workbook and I would like to **copy the values contained in all the cells of the first worksheet to a second one**, within the same workbook.

I tried with:

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet("Worksheet 1")

ws_1 = wb.add_worksheet("Worksheet 2")
ws_1 = ws
```

But it doesn't work; how can I do that using the aforementioned library?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to copy the values contained in all the cells of the first worksheet to a second one

There is no mechanism in XlsxWriter to copy data, or manipulate it in any way, once it goes into the workbook/worksheet objects.

However, if you want to write the same data to one or more worksheets you could iterate over the worksheets like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

ws_1 = wb.add_worksheet("Worksheet 1")
ws_2 = wb.add_worksheet("Worksheet 2")

for worksheet in wb.worksheets():
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello')
    worksheet.write(1, 0, 'World')

wb.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get Help from [xlsxwriter site](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/page_setup.html)

and you can use this to copy parameter in one of worksheet to other woorksheet

```
import xlsxwriter


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet1.write('A1', 123)
expenses = (
    ['Rent', '=sheet1!A1'],
    ['Gas',   '=sheet1!A1'],
    ['Food',  '=sheet1!A1'],
    ['Gym',    '=sheet1!A1'],
)

row = 0
col = 0

for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet2.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet2.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer; however, it does not minimally solve the problem I have.

Comment: maybe the question is vague; but please read carefully that I need to copy **all the values in the first sheet to the second one**! Not to only create a second sheet. Thank you

Comment: you can check this if you want to copy from on of worksheet to other